Change "Add to Cart" Button to Add Free Sample Product Instead
I am working on a WooCommerce store where I offer free samples of the products. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:
Button behavior: I have renamed the default "Add to Cart" button to "Free Sample."
Goal:
When a customer clicks the "Free Sample" button, I want it to add a different product (the corresponding free sample product) to the cart instead of the regular product.
Free sample product: The free sample is a separate product with a price set to £0.
Setup:
I have already renamed the "Add to Cart" button to "Free Sample" on both the shop and product pages, and I like how it looks and is positioned.
Each regular product has a corresponding free sample product, which is set up as a separate product in WooCommerce and priced at £0.
The code I've Tried: (in functions.php)
I added the following code to my functions.php file to handle the button functionality and product ID swapping.
// Modify the Add to Cart button text to 'Free Sample'
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'change_add_to_cart_button_text');
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'change_add_to_cart_button_text');

function change_add_to_cart_button_text() {
    return __('Free Sample', 'woocommerce'); // Button says 'Free Sample'
}

// Ensure the correct free sample product is added to cart when the Free Sample button is clicked
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_free_sample_to_cart', 10, 3);
function add_free_sample_to_cart($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['is_free_sample']) && $_POST['is_free_sample'] === 'true') {
        // Get the corresponding free sample product ID from the array
        $free_sample_id = get_free_sample_product_id($product_id);

        if ($free_sample_id) {
            $cart_item_data['product_id'] = $free_sample_id; // Replace the product ID with the free sample product ID
        }
    }

    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Mapping of original products to free sample product IDs
function get_free_sample_product_id($product_id) {
    $free_samples = array(
        350 => 2658, // Original Product => Free Sample Product
        353 => 2657,
        362 => 2656,
        368 => 2653,
        371 => 2652,
        // More mappings...
    );

    return isset($free_samples[$product_id]) ? $free_samples[$product_id] : false;
}

The Problem:
Even after implementing the above solution:
Clicking the "Free Sample" button still adds the original product to the cart (with the regular price), not the free sample product priced at £0.
There are no console errors, and the button looks and functions normally in terms of its position and styling.
I have tried several approaches, including overriding add-to-cart behavior, but nothing seems to work as intended. I want the button to seamlessly add the free sample product based on the mapping instead of the main product.
What I’m Looking For: 
How to correctly swap the product being added to the cart with its free sample counterpart?
Does my current approach is appropriated?
Additional Context:
I’m using the WoodMart theme, but the main WooCommerce functionality should still apply. The button already has the correct label "Free Sample," and I just need to ensure that the corresponding free sample product is added to the cart.
